# Azure Maps - How to put a map line layer into edit mode?

Tags: azure-maps

I create a line layer and add it to the map.

But I then need to put this line layer into edit mode the user can stretch and manipulate the line, or whatever shape that I had added to the map.

The only reference I could find in MS Docs is how to put a 'shape' into edit mode, but this does not seem to be relevant and after trying their example, nothing works for me.

```
//Create a data source and add it to the map.
var dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
map.sources.add(dataSource);

//Create a line and add it to the data source.
dataSource.add(new atlas.data.LineString([[-73.972340, 40.743270], [-74.004420, 40.756800]]));
  
//Create a line layer to render the line to the map.
map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.LineLayer(dataSource, null, {
    strokeColor: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: 5
}));
```

[image]

The code above creates the line, renders it to the map, but when clicking/hovering over the line I can't select it to edit it, really need some help with the missing code to do this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the drawing module for that. It allows you to create a `DrawingManager` to edit a shape by setting the mode to `edit-geometry`.

I reworked a bit your example with the `LineString` to put it automatically on edit when the map is ready.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>AzureMaps</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css"
        type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/drawing/1/atlas-drawing.min.css"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/drawing/1/atlas-drawing.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function GetMap() {
            //Initialize a map instance.
            const map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                view: 'Auto',
                center: [-73.972340, 40.743270],
                zoom: 13,

                //Add your Azure Maps key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps. NOTE: The primary key should be used as the key.
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: '<enter-your-subscription-key>'
                }
            });

            map.events.add('ready', () => {
                //Create a data source and add it to the map.
                var dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
                map.sources.add(dataSource);

                const lineString = new atlas.data.LineString([[-73.972340, 40.743270], [-74.004420, 40.756800]]);

                //Create a line and add it to the data source.
                dataSource.add(lineString);
                const lineStringShape = dataSource.getShapes()[0];

                //Create a line layer to render the line to the map.
                map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.LineLayer(dataSource, null, {
                    strokeColor: 'blue',
                    strokeWidth: 5
                }));

                var drawingManager = new atlas.drawing.DrawingManager(map, {
                    mode: 'edit-geometry'
                });

                drawingManager.edit(lineStringShape);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:100%;min-width:290px;height:600px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: LineString on edit mode]

Important thing is, you need to reference the atlas-drawing scripts and styles :

```
<script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/drawing/1/atlas-drawing.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/drawing/1/atlas-drawing.min.css"
        type="text/css" />
```

You can find more information on the Drawing Manager [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-drawing-tools/atlas.drawing.drawingmanager?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest).

### Edit - Change only color and width

If you want to change only the `strokeColor` and the `strokeWidth` of your line string, you don't actually need the drawing manager for that. I would recommend to set expressions on the `strokeColor` and `strokeWidth` of your line layer to read the values from the properties of each shape.

The following example displays two line strings with different width and colors :

```
 //Initialize a map instance.
            const map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                view: 'Auto',
                center: [-73.972340, 40.743270],
                zoom: 13,

                //Add your Azure Maps key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps. NOTE: The primary key should be used as the key.
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: '<enter-your-subscription-key>'
                }
            });

            map.events.add('ready', () => {
                //Create a data source and add it to the map.
                const dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
                map.sources.add(dataSource);

                const firstLineString = new atlas.data.LineString([[-73.972340, 40.743270], [-74.004420, 40.756800]]);
                const secondLineString = new atlas.data.LineString([[-73.972340, 40.733270], [-74.004420, 40.746800]]);

                //Create a line and add it to the data source.
                dataSource.add(firstLineString);
                dataSource.add(secondLineString);

                //Add properties on the shapes
                const shapes = dataSource.getShapes()
                const firstLineStringShape = shapes[0];
                firstLineStringShape.addProperty('color', '#ed5a10');
                firstLineStringShape.addProperty('strokeWidth', 10);

                const secondLineStringShape = shapes[1];
                secondLineStringShape.addProperty('color', '#0e41ea');
                secondLineStringShape.addProperty('strokeWidth', 5);

                //Create a line layer to render the line to the map.
                //strokeColor and strokeWidth are defined on the properties of each line string
                map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.LineLayer(dataSource, null, {
                    strokeColor: ['get', 'color'],
                    strokeWidth: ['get', 'strokeWidth']
                }));
            });
```

It is still done when the map is ready in this example for convenience, but you can set the properties of a shape whenever you need to update it using either `addProperty` if your property was never set, or a combination of `getProperties` and `setProperties`.

You can find more information on the data driven expressions here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/data-driven-style-expressions-web-sdk

Comment: Hi, I'm never going to add a line as soon as the map is rendered, I'm trying to get this working based on a line that has already been drawn. Drawing the line works, but I need to figure out how to select/click on the line to edit it. I cant rely on the drawing tools toolbar either which is my preferred solution, becuase it seems a line drawn uisng the toolbar doesnt allow us to later update the line appearence, such as changing the colour and strokewidth. I'm so confused wth this api... thanks anyway

Comment: I tried testing your example, but when the blue line is shown and put into edit mode, if I then drag the shape of the line, i find a black line underneath it which is the one thats actually put into edit mode, so the blue line is just static.

Comment: I think my confusion is that I expect to be able to edit a lineString and change its appearence such as stroke width and color, but it seems that we can only modify the line layer, not each individually drawn lineString? I want to be able to edit each individual line drawn with its own appearence, not trigger a global change to all lines drawn.

Comment: If your goal is only to change the color and the width, you don't need the drawing manager for that, you could simply use expressions on those two fields of your line layer and read the values out of the properties of each line string. I edited my answer to provide you an example and show you how it could be done

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I started looking at expressiosns last night but hadnt quite got my head around it. I just got to figure out how to access the shape without knowing which index it currently sits within the drawing manager array, something like finding it by clicking on it when the drawing manager is in edit mode.